# Is there a way to make sure Decimal('0) times something returns actually 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

Using python 3.4.3 or python 3.5.1 I'm surprised to see that:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal('0') * Decimal('123.456789123456')
```

returns:

```
Decimal('0E-12')
```

Worse part is that this specific use case works with float.

Is there anything I could do to make sure the maths work and 0 multiplied by anything returns 0?

Comment: That is technically 0. How are you planning to use the result?

Comment: The number is so small that it is basically 0, as @Nicarus said. Could you round to a few decimal places?

Comment: `Decimal('0E-12') == Decimal('0')` gives `True`, while `Decimal('1E-12') == Decimal('0')` gives `False`. So I think `Decimal('0E-12')` is not *approximately* 0, it *is* 0 in Python.

Comment: `0E-12` means `0 * 10^(-12)` which is `0`

Comment: Off topic, but 3.5.2 has been out for a while... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0E-12` actually is `0` (it's short for `0 * 10 ** -12`; since the coefficient is 0, that's still 0), `Decimal` just provides the `E-12` bit to indicate the "confidence level" of the `0`. What you've got will still behave like zero (it's falsy, additive identity, etc.), the only quirk is in how it prints.

If you need formatting to match, you can use the formatting mini-language, or you can call `.normalize()` on the result, which will turn `Decimal('0E-12')` into `Decimal('0')` (the method's purpose is to strip trailing zeroes from the result to produce a minimal canonical form that represents all equal numbers the same way).

Comment: Silly me... 0E-12 is indeed 0. Thanks for the answer and the pointer to .normalize() if i need to display the result somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `Decimal('0E-12')` is not visually the same as `Decimal('0')`, there is no difference to python.

```
>>> Decimal('0E-12') == 0
True
```

The notation 0E-12 actually represents: 0 * 10 ** -12. This expression evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You may quantize your result to required precision.

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
result = Decimal('0') * Decimal('123.456789123456')
result.quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP)

>>>Decimal('0.00')
```

For more info (eg. about rounding modes or even setting up a context for all decimals) refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Edit: I guess your best hit would be using `result.normalize()` method as mentioned by ShadowRanger.

Answer (score -3):

Do the multiplication with floats and convert to decimal afterwards.

```
x = 0
y = 123.456789123456
Decimal(x*y)
```

returns (on Python 3.5.2):

```
Decimal('0')
```

Comment: That completely defeats the point of using `Decimal` in the first place.